# How to access a Vue Js variable from Spring MVC?

Tags: spring-boot, vue.js, spring-mvc

I am fairly new to Vue JS. I have a model with many fields and the user is supposed to update one of its fields through a checkbox. After this, the user would click on a button **Submit** to submit his response.

My problem is, I am unable to access this variable from Spring MVC. Essentially I would like to take the response and update the h2 database from Spring MVC.

I tried @RequestParam but it is throwing an error.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{reader}/datasetSummary", method= RequestMethod.POST,params="Submit")
    public String submitUserLabelling(
            @RequestParam(name= "datasetSummary") List<Asset> assetList) {
```

**Note**, the user does not enter all the fields for a model. He just updates one of the fields.

Any help on this?

**Edit: ** My model attribute name is **datasetSummary**

Comment: whats the error?

Comment: @brijesh Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon Nov 30 11:29:04 IST 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).

Comment: Check if the URL is similar to the mapping, method is POST and is param "Submit" sent in request from client. Else make param as optional

Comment: @brijesh this is my form. <form action="/reading/datasetSummary" method="POST">
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" class="button" value="Submit"></input>
    </form>

Comment: In case I was unable to make my intentions clear, with the help of this post request, I want to be able to access a vue js variable from the server side so that I can update my model. Hence the use of @RequestParam is an attempt to get hold of a vue js variable

Comment: Check in nwtwork tab of Chrome, whats the URL in the request when you click on submit. If thats matching, check if submit goes in params in the body